# Select2 remote data search once all data retrieved

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

The select2 is almost working how I want it. It loads all the remote data and formats its correctly when another field is changed. I want to add back in the search function on the retrieved data i.e. once the data is retrieved, the user can search the list by the title (result.title).

In the example below, the data is retrieved, but the search term is not being filtered. It is important that all the remote data be loaded first before the user has to search for a result.

If I cant add the ability to search, how do I disable the search box? If I set "minimumResultsForSearch: -1", the select2 box still lets me search?

[image: example]

```
    var $company2 = $(".company2");
    $company2.select2().on('change', function() {
        if ($company2.val() !== null) {
            $('.unmaintained2').select2({
                allowClear: true,
                minimumResultsForSearch: 1,
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/unmaintained2/" + $company2.val(),
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results: data,
                        };
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: true,
                },
                escapeMarkup: function(m) {
                    return m;
                },
                templateResult: function (result) {
                    if (result.loading) return 'Loading...';
                    return result.text + '<h6>' + result.make + ' ' + result.category + '</h6>';
                },
            });
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dns_nx below is the final solution! The select2 is now searchable (client side) and templatable with remote data!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $company2 = $(".company2");
    var $equipment2 = $(".equipment2");
    $company2.select2().on('change', function() {
        $equipment2.empty();
        if ($company2.val() !== null) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/') }}" + "/api/unmaintained2/" + $company2.val(),
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    $equipment2.select2({
                        data: data,
                        templateSelection: function(result) {
                            return result.text;
                        },
                        templateResult: function(result) {
                            if (!result.id) {
                                return result.text;
                            }
                            var final = '<h2>'+ result.serial + '</h2><h5>(' + result.make  + ') ' + result.category + '</h5>';
                            return final;
                        },
                        escapeMarkup: function(result) {
                            return result;
                        },
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for searching called `matcher`. See the docs

https://select2.org/searching#customizing-how-results-are-matched

But this you can only use with local supplied data.

If you are using remote data, `select2` expects the data is returned already filtered.

> matcher only works with locally supplied data (e.g., via an array!
>   When a remote data set is used, Select2 expects that the returned
>   results have already been filtered on the server side.

So I think, you cannot use this way with the `ajax` option.

Maybe you can load the data when the page is loaded and then add the returned data as `option`s into the select box. Then initiliaze the `select2` box with the `matcher` option.

**UPDATE:**

I've played around a little bit and you can format the search results after loading all options. 
Check this code:

```
function formatState (state) {
  if (!state.id) {
    return state.text;
  }
  var state1 = state.text + '<h6>(' + state.id  + ') ' + state.text + '</h6>';
  return state1;
};

function selection(state) {
    return state.text;
}

function makeSelect2(data) {
    $('#selectBox').select2({
        data: data,
        templateSelection: selection,
        templateResult: formatState,
        escapeMarkup: function (state) {
            return state;
        },
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: ({ 
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            makeSelect2(data);
        }
    });
});
```

On `$(document).ready` the options are loaded via `ajax`. After successful `ajax` result the function `makeSelect2` is called with the result from the `ajax` request. 
In the `makeSelect2` function, the `select2` box is initialized with the given data and using the `templateSelection` and `templateResult` options, you can modify your search result look.

Hope that's what your expecting.

Comment: Thanks - that is what I thought! I previously had the select2 adding each item as an "option", but I do not know how to use the "templateResult" function with this?

Comment: I'm testing out something. I will let you know my test results.